# Loop an observable in Angular2

Tags: angular, asynchronous

How can I simply loop an observable?

Let's say I want to execute an observable five times it would go something like the code below.

What happens in my code is that

(1) I query and a function returns a json called 'posts'

(2) for every 'posts' I want to execute an observable

(3) I push the result of step (2) to my array

```
// (1)
this.communityPostProvider.query({})
  .subscribe(posts => {

    // (2)
    for(let i=0; i < posts.length; i++) {
        this.getFeaturedApi(i)
        .subscribe(result => {
            // (3)
            this.communityPosts.push(posts[i]);
            this.communityPosts[i].featured_media = result;      
      });
   });
```

The problem with this is that the for loop completely executes before my observable can. By the time the observable executes, the for loop is already finished.

I am new to angular2. Please help!

Comment: Off topic, but all I see is a bunch of potential memory leaks waiting to happen

Comment: in for loop you're subscribing to multiple observables, observables are not meant to be awaited, they subscribed to the data when observable emit it, however what issue you are facing here, as the observables will do their job when they have something in result.

Comment: @A.T. do you have advice on how I can work around this? I really need to loop this..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
this.communityPostProvider.query({})
  .map(posts => {
     for(var i=0; i<posts.length; i++){
     this.getFeaturedApi(i)
        .subscribe(result=> {
            posts[i].featured_media = result;
            this.communityPosts.push(posts[i]);
     }
     return posts;
   })
  .subscribe(posts => {
     // your posts with featured_media
   });
```

If using rxjs >= 5.5 use `.pipe(map(...))`

To learn how to use map and other rxjs operators, [here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-observables/)

To learn about new rxjs lettable functions, [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-lettable-operators-fe74dda186d3)

Comment: when I print the i, it's equal to posts.length.. it's still not looping :(

Comment: it depends on how the data is returned. Check out the first link to know about how map works. It'll help you.

Comment: and how does `posts` look like?

Comment: there's no problem on the data.. :< posts gives the json that im looking for.. it's just that I receive the error: " ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'featured_media' of undefined" on this line " this.communityPosts[i].featured_media = result;"

Comment: I don't have problems waiting for the Observables, I have a problem with using the for loop ..

Comment: getting a look at the `posts` object would have helped.

Comment: it's simply an array of these: 
{id: 6802, date: "2017-02-21T16:45:55", date_gmt: "2017-02-22T00:45:55", guid: {…}, modified: "2017-02-21T16:47:19", …}

Comment: Sorry, did not notice it before. Please check my updated answer. @Domy

Answer (score 0):

if you able edit your code in function

```
this.getFeaturedApi(i)
```

when you return the result just pass the "i" back together with the result, so the endpoint will know which index to push in the array.

For example.

```
this.getFeaturedApi(i:number){
// your code 
return {result:result, index:i};
```

and in your for loop

```
// (2)
for(let i=0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    this.getFeaturedApi(i)
    .subscribe(result => {
        // (3)
        this.communityPosts.push(posts[result.index);
        this.communityPosts[result.index].featured_media = result.result;      
  });
```

Now you recieve the result with index. So you know exacty which index to push in array.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `flatMap` in conjunction with `range` and `combineLatest` to get a nice stream of results.

This version is rather similar to your structure.

```
this.communityPostProvider.query({})
  .flatMap(posts => {
    return Observable.range(0, posts.length-1)
    .map(i=> {
        return {index: i, post: posts[i]};
    })
  })
  .flatMap(postWithIndex => Observable.forkJoin([Observable.of(postWithIndex), this.getFeaturedApi(postWithIndex.index)])
  .subscribe(result => {
    // result = [{index: i, post: posts[i]}, resultFromFeature]
    this.communityPosts.push(result[0].post]);
    this.communityPosts[result[0].index].featured_media = result[1];      
  });
```

But I would recommend to refactor to this as it it a lot cleaner and more in line with a streaming api.

```
this.communityPostProvider.query({})
  .flatMap(posts => {
    return Observable.range(0, posts.length-1)
    .map(i=> {
        return {index: i, post: posts[i]};
    })
  })
  .flatMap(postWithIndex => Observable.forkJoin([Observable.of(postWithIndex.post), this.getFeaturedApi(postWithIndex.index)]))
  .map(postAndResult => {
      // result = [post, resultFromFeature]
      postAndResult[0].featured_media = postAndResult[1]
      return postAndResult[0];
  })
  .subscribe(postWithFeaturedMedia => {
    this.communityPosts.push(postWithFeaturedMedia);
  });
```

(This is untested, as I don't have a working rxjs setup atm.)

Answer (score 0):

**This is also untested**.

[mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) will take a value and return an inner observable.

So we take the array of posts and use Observable's [from](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html) operator to emit each item of the array individually, again using mergeMap to map each value to an observable, in this case the observable returned from the call to `getFeaturedApi`, passing in the index that was given to us as an argument to mergeMap.

We use [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) to assign the retrieved `feature` to the associated `post`.

```
this.communityPostProvider.query({})
    .mergeMap((posts) => {
        return Observable.from(posts).mergeMap((post, index) => {
            this.communityPosts.push(post);
            return this.getFeaturedApi(index).map((feature) => {
                this.communityPosts[index] = feature;
                return feature;
            });
        });
    })
    .subscribe();
```

Depending on your needs, you can return `feature` or `post` from the map operating on `getFeaturedApi`. Whatever is returned will be available within your `subscribe` function.